# Global scope or permanent length or savebox

Tags: grouping

I am trying to save a minipage width and height in one environment, and use these dimensions in a subsequent environment of mine, to make a picture environment.
The idea is to create a picture on the right of the minipage using the rest of the `\columnwidth`, and with the same height as the minipage on the left.
The problem is, as far as I understand, that neither the lengths nor the `\savebox`'es set within the first environment survive to the next one, as they are subject to scoping rules of LaTeX.

So my question is, how can save dimensions (or the box) in one environment and use them in another?

Update: here is (non-working) example using `\global`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{picture}

\newsavebox{\questiontextbox}
\newsavebox{\questionpicturebox}
\newlength{\questiontextheight}

\newenvironment{questiontext}[1]%
{\begin{lrbox}{\questiontextbox}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}}%
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\noindent\usebox{\questiontextbox}%
\settoheight{\questiontextheight}{\usebox{\questiontextbox}}% ****
\global\setlength{\questiontextheight}{\questiontextheight}}

\newenvironment{questionpicture}[1]%
{\begin{lrbox}{\questionpicturebox}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
\begin{picture}(#1-\fboxsep-\fboxsep,\questiontextheight)}%
{\end{picture}\end{lrbox}%
\fbox{\raisebox{-\questiontextheight}{\usebox{\questionpicturebox}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questiontext}{0.2\columnwidth}
There must be some text here so I made it up to fill more than just a
single line.
\end{questiontext}%
\begin{questionpicture}{0.8\columnwidth}
\put(0.5,0.5){\circle{0.4}}
\end{questionpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `\fbox` is there only to visualize that the picture height is only two `\fboxsep`'s. I tried to put `\global` before `\settoheight` in the line marked with ****, which does not work, either. No idea what I am doing wrong; could the packages `calc` or `picture` (which is needed to use real dimensions) prevent proper `\global` behaviour?

[image: the result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a primitive `\global` that makes a following TeX assignment global.  So you can use `\global\setbox` and `\global\def` = `\gdef`.  In LaTeX as David Carlisle kindly points out you may get away with `\global\setlength` in some circumstances, but in general it is not guaranteed to work, and loading packages such as `calc` in fact prevents it working.  One work around is to use an intermediate global TeX assignment of the result of a calculation via `\global\len=\len` after the `\setlength`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylength}
\newlength{\myglength}
\newlength{\myllength}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\mylength}{10pt}
\setlength{\myglength}{10pt}
\setlength{\myllength}{10pt}

\verb+\mylength+ is \the\mylength.
\verb+\myglength+ is \the\myglength.
\verb+\myllength+ is \the\myllength.

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\setlength{\mylength}{20pt}
\setlength{\myglength}{20pt}
\global\setlength{\myllength}{20pt} % Doesn't work when calc is loaded
\global\myglength=\myglength
Minipage start

\verb+\mylength+ is \the\mylength.
\verb+\myglength+ is \the\myglength.
\verb+\myllength+ is \the\myllength.

Minigage end
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\verb+\mylength+ is \the\mylength.
\verb+\myglength+ is \the\myglength.
\verb+\myllength+ is \the\myllength.
\end{document}
```

In the specific example you now give, you need to get hold of the `totalheight` of the box, to get a picture of the same height and this then needs to be shifted down by the `depth` of the minipage.  The above `\global` tricks will now work:

[image: Sample application output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newsavebox{\questiontextbox}
\newsavebox{\questionpicturebox}
\newlength{\questiontexttotalheight}
\newlength{\questiontextdepth}

\newenvironment{questiontext}[1]%
{\begin{lrbox}{\questiontextbox}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}}%
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \noindent\usebox{\questiontextbox}%
  \settototalheight{\questiontexttotalheight}{\usebox{\questiontextbox}}%
  \settodepth{\questiontextdepth}{\usebox{\questiontextbox}}%
  \global\questiontexttotalheight=\questiontexttotalheight
  \global\questiontextdepth=\questiontextdepth}

\newenvironment{questionpicture}[1]%
{\begin{lrbox}{\questionpicturebox}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
  \begin{picture}(#1-\fboxsep-\fboxsep-0.8pt,\questiontexttotalheight)}%
{\end{picture}\end{lrbox}%
  \fbox{\raisebox{-\questiontextdepth}{\usebox{\questionpicturebox}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questiontext}{0.2\columnwidth}
  \RaggedRight There must be some text here so I made it up to fill more than just
  a single line.
\end{questiontext}%
\begin{questionpicture}{0.8\columnwidth}
  \put(0.5,0.5){\circle{0.4}}
\end{questionpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have changed a couple of extra things in your code.  Firstly, the width of your `\fbox` has not only the `\fboxsep` but two rules `0.4pt` wide, so you need to substract `0.8pt` more to avoid an overfull box.  Secondly, the narrow column on the left is better set ragged right, using the `ragged2e` package provides the `\RaggedRight` command which is less drastic than standard `\raggedright`.

Comment: `\global` isn't guaranteed to work as a prefix to latex assignments. It won't work if the `calc` package is loaded. `\global\myglength=20pt` is much safer.

Comment: Or you can use \setlength{\global...

Comment: Global assignments with `\setlength` that survives package `calc`: `\setlength{\mylength}{...}\global\mylength=\mylength`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek That seems to be the best general approach.

Comment: Thank you for answers! It looks like I missed a lot while playing with `\global` and preparing my example. I will try it out.

Comment: This is a great and prompt answer indeed. I had to get away from the computer for a while and now I find a complete and polished solution. Thank you!