# Behavior of \global when used with xifthen package

Tags: lengths, grouping, xifthen

I'm trying to calculate the sum of some numbers in my document. I want to allow non-integer values, so I'm using lengths, which works just fine.

In my document it's often necessary to specify the values for adding to the sum from inside an environment. I learned that the `\global` command does the trick.

However, I encountered the problem that the `\global` command seems to not work properly when the `xifthen` package is loaded, either directly or by another package.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\getlength}[1]{\strip@pt#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{0pt}
\getlength{\mylength}
{
    \addtolength{\mylength}{0.5pt}
    \getlength{\mylength}
}
\getlength{\mylength}
{
    \global\addtolength{\mylength}{0.5pt}
    \getlength{\mylength}
}
\getlength{\mylength}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
0 0.5 0 0.5 0
```

Removing the `xifthen` package produces the expected output:

```
0 0.5 0 0.5 0.5
```

Is there any workaround to produce the second output, without having to ensure that no package which uses `xifthen` is loaded?

Comment: `\global\addtolength` is wrong anyway. The problem is that `xifthen` loads `calc` that redefines `\addtolength` so that `\global` has no effect (but it has effect without `calc` just by chance). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119738/4427