# Defining macro \gsetlength as global setlength, reliable?

Tags: lengths, grouping

As is noted in other questions, such as [Global scope or permanent length or savebox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119730/global-scope-or-permanent-length-or-savebox), the `\setlength` command does not always have global effect. In many cases, that is desirable. But when the effect must be global, using `\global\setlength` often does not work.

I tend to think globally, so to speak. In most cases, when I set a length, I expect it to be nailed down. So I often have to write expressions like this: `\setlength\something{value}\global\something=\something`. That works well.

So I ask myself, why not define a macro `\gsetlength` that does it all? MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% Using LuaLaTeX because I use it in real documents. Probably the same in pdflatex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} % Because I use it in real documents.
\gdef\gsetlength#1#2{\setlength#1{#2}\global#1=#1} % Should this always be OK ?
%
\newlength\mylengthone
\setlength\mylengthone{1pt}
\newlength\mylengthtwo
\setlength\mylengthtwo{2pt}
%
\newlength\mylengththree
\gsetlength\mylengththree{3pt}
\newlength\mylengthfour
\gsetlength\mylengthfour{4pt}
%
\newlength\mytesta % one level of global
\gsetlength\mytesta{\mylengthone+\mylengthtwo}
\newlength\mytestb % two levels of global
\gsetlength\mytestb{\mylengththree+\mylengthfour}
%
\newlength\mytestc
{\setlength\mytestc{\mylengthone+\mylengthtwo}} % Grouped, not global
\newlength\mytestd
{\gsetlength\mytestd{\mylengthone+\mylengthtwo}} % Grouped, global.
%
\begin{document}
\the\mytesta\par % Expecting 3.0pt.
\the\mytestb\par % Expecting 7.0pt.
\the\mytestc\par % Expecting 0.0pt because \setlength was within group.
\the\mytestd\par % Expecting 3.0pt because \gsetlength.
\end{document}
```

The above code works as expected. Now for my question: Is it something that I can always expect to work, especially since I use the `calc` package? Or am I in danger of bumping up against hidden expansion or catcode problems?

Using `\gsetlength` makes my code shorter, and more readable. But I am nervous...

EDIT: Provided longer MWE per request by DC.

EDIT2: For most users, the information provided by David Carlisle will be what you need. That is, inspect your code to ensure that you are not setting the length in such a way that it is locally limited to a group, which might be delimited by extraneous braces.

But in my own case, the answer provided by Heiko was accepted. That's because I have a very large document class, with numerous nested conditionals and values that are manipulated and passed from place to place. The number of them is not so large as to use of all TeX resources, because once my main document text begins, it does not use a lot of code that would choke TeX. In particular, I am not using TiKz, bibliography, or anything like that.

LATE EDIT: I just discovered the `\deflength` command, in the `etoolbox` package. According to its description, it supports `\global` when requested (unlike `\setlength`).

Comment: why would you need this (often) certainly it's not needed in any of the settings in this example which all have global scope anyway. (If you do want to do this you would be better to make the original assignment to an always local scratch register than globally assign to your always global `#1` otherwise you can kill the save stack.

Comment: do you have an example where you need to set a length with global scope from inside a group?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  The MWE is "too minimal." I do not need it in the MWE, but in a vast document structure that passes lengths back and forth. The master document loads several component files, which communicate with each other, generally in response to conditional tests. In many cases, lengths are set AtBeginDocument or AtEndPreamble, or within the subsequent document body. I have discovered that, in many cases, I must use global lengths, or the components do not communicate properly. EDIT: I will work on a "grouped" example and get back. Later.

Comment: hmmm both the standard AtBeginDocument hook and the contributed AtEndPreamble hook are executed at the top level not inside a group, so I remain to be convinced:-) Using global assignments  like any use of global variables in any software is using a massive dangerous sledgehammer that can easily break more than the problem it's intended to break

Comment: Whenever I see something like `\global\let#1=#1` my eyes weep.

Comment: @RobtAll finally a good justification for this code ^^^^

Comment: @egreg That's why I only write TeX in the rain, so nobody can tell.

Comment: following the edit, the correct fix is to remove the spurious groups, not to make the assignments global (this is a real comment, for once:-) in that before making global assignments I would investigate why your assignments are in a local scope and seeing if that can be changed.  If you really want to do it defining it as `\newcommand\gsetlength[2]{\setlength\@tempskipa{#2}\global#1\@tempskipa}` will work but it is unlikely to be the best solution to the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand about the spurious groups. But that's part of the MWE. In "real code" I have braced groups all over the place, usually for reasons that go beyond setting a length.

Comment: Yes I realise that the groups in the mwe are just examples, but still I would look to see (in your real documents) if the assignments can be moved to a better place rather than routinely needing global assignments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Alas, it is strewn in 210kB of my own code (`novel` document class). Works, no problem, but I seek to improve its internal readability. Let me put this off for awhile, and I hope to get back with a more direct example in the not-near future. The problem with groupings is that they are often hard to detect, when there are thousands of braces here and there, often needed for nested conditionals. When I use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` I really mean it.

Comment: @RobtAll the sledgehammer it is then:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The mixed assignments, local and global, are already addressed by David's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406021/16967).
- The ending of the macro definition with `#1` in `\global#1=#1` is quite dangerous. Consider `#1` as `\dimen1` (odd register numbers < 10 are for global assigments) and the next tokens are '012345foo'. Then, TeX tries to assign `\global\dimen1=\dimen1012345`. This is fixed by ending the assignment by `\relax`.

Suggestion for an improved version:

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\gsetlength#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength\skip@{#2}% Local assignment to a scratch register.
    \global#1=\skip@    % Global assignement to #1;
                        % \relax is not necessary because of the following \endgroup.
  \endgroup             % \skip@ is restored by end of group.
}
\makeatother
```

The local assignment of `\setlength` is done to the local scratch register `\skip@` inside a group. Then the global assignment to `#1` is done. After the group end, the locally changed value of `\skip@` is restored, but the globally assigned `\skip@` keeps the value.

Comment: Excellent point. Seems that `\relax` is needed in my original code. The improved code is a bit arcane, but does the job.

Comment: @RobtAll. The updated answer uses `\skip@` instead of `\dimen@`, because `\setlength` covers both. An explanation is added to make it less "arcane".

Answer (score 4):

The save stack on modern systems is a lot larger than it used to be but still the `\global#1=#1` idiom uses it up and will cause fatal error if done often enough

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\zzz
\newlength\Lzzz

\newcount\ccc

\begin{document}

{

\loop
\Lzzz=5pt \global\zzz=\Lzzz
\Lzzz=6pt \global\zzz=\Lzzz
\ifnum\ccc<20000
\advance\ccc 1
\repeat

}
\end{document}
```

runs without error and the log shows

```
 23i,1n,17p,109b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

so at most 36 stack positions were used up (which is in latex core code, not the code visible in the document)

However if you try the version using a single length and making local and global settings to the same register:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\zzz

\newcount\ccc

\begin{document}

{

\loop
\zzz=5pt \global\zzz=\zzz
\zzz=6pt \global\zzz=\zzz
\ifnum\ccc<20000
\advance\ccc 1
\repeat

}
\end{document}
```

Then you get no output just:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.16 \repeat

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

and all 80000 save stack positions have been used up saving values of the register.

This is why registers are always separated between local and global use, for example the scratch register with odd numbers, 1,3,5,7,9 are always used globally and those with even numbers, 0,2,4,6,8 are always used locally.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that. Will investigate further, and get back later.