# Adapting double math-mode accents for different math styles

Tags: math-mode, accents

I'm using a slightly generalized version of @wipet's [excellent code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586604/158639) for double hats in math mode that allows for arbitrary double accents (see below for the code). This works fine, but I now noticed that the spacing is (once again) off when you use different math styles (i.e. `\displaystyle` and friends). Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\def\measureaccent#1#2{%
   \setbox0=\vbox{$#1{#2}\hfil\break$\null\par
      \setbox0=\lastbox\unskip\unpenalty\global\setbox1=\lastbox}%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox1 \unskip\unpenalty\unskip \global\setbox2=\lastbox}%
   \setbox0=\vbox{\unvbox2 \setbox0=\lastbox}%
}
\def\doubleaccent#1#2{%
   \measureaccent{#1}{#2}\dimen0=\wd0 \measureaccent{#1}{\kern0pt#2}%
   \raise.35ex\rlap{\kern\dimexpr\dimen0-\wd0$#1{\phantom{#2}}$}{#1#2}%
}
\def\doubletilde#1{\doubleaccent\tilde#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ \textstyle \doubletilde k \qquad \scriptstyle \doubletilde k \qquad \scriptscriptstyle \doubletilde k \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, in `\textstyle` (and `\displaystyle`) the result looks fine, but it gets worse from there.

Ideally I'd like for `\doubleaccent` to work with no further further intervention from my side in all styles. I imagine `\measureaccent` would have to be adapted for this; it looks like the measuring is done without regard for the current style, but I yet lack the skills to do this myself, and would therefore greatly appreciate the help of the resident wizards. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I should note that @wipet's answer solved a problem with horizontal alignment of the accents that I'd ideally like to not reintroduce.

**EDIT 2:** here's another snippet showing why I'm creating double accents this way to begin with:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{statmath}
\def\measureaccent#1#2{%
   \setbox0=\vbox{$#1{#2}\hfil\break$\null\par
      \setbox0=\lastbox\unskip\unpenalty\global\setbox1=\lastbox}%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox1 \unskip\unpenalty\unskip \global\setbox3=\lastbox}%
   \setbox0=\vbox{\unvbox3 \setbox0=\lastbox}%
}
\def\doubleaccent#1#2{%
   \measureaccent{#1}{#2}\dimen0=\wd0 \measureaccent{#1}{\kern0pt#2}%
   \raise.35ex\rlap{\kern\dimexpr\dimen0-\wd0$#1{\phantom{#2}}$}{#1#2}%
}
\def\doubletilde#1{\doubleaccent\tilde#1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ \tilde\beta \quad \tilde{\tilde\beta} \quad \doubletilde\beta \quad \tilde\bfbeta \quad \tilde{\tilde\bfbeta} \quad \doubletilde\bfbeta \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The single `\tilde` is fine for both `\beta` and `\bfbeta`. Nested `\tilde`s are too far apart and give the impression of two single tildes rather than a one double tilde (unsurprising, given that that's what they are). In addition, on the `\bfbeta`, they're positioned too far on the left.

(I usually don't use double accents outside of `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`, and when I do it's usually on bold-face Greek or Latin letters. I just so happened to reach for `\doubletilde` today when defining another abbreviation in an `\underbrace` and when I already had `k` and `\tilde k`, and then noticed the above.)

Comment: What's wrong with `\tilde{\tilde{k}}` (using `amsmath` or `mathtools`)?

Comment: @egreg The horizontal spacing is off (see the question to the answer linked); and I'd prefer for the two tildes to be a little closer as well, giving the visual impression of a double tilde rather than two single tildes.

Comment: @chsk what is wrong with the horizontal position of [the standard amsmath version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLrg8.png) ? or [hat on beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsuFW.png) ?

Comment: also don't use even boxes for global settings `\global\setbox2=` that should be box3 not box2

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the pointer re: even boxes. Out of curiosity, why's that? And is there a "List O' Pitfalls" somewhere that tells you about things like these?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle re: what's wrong with the standard stuff, I'll edit my post.

Comment: the convention on odd and even scratch registers is set out in the texbook, I'm sure there is an answer on site I'll find...  More generally even for registers allocated with \new...  they should always be local or always global.

Comment: not the one I was thinking of but https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406227/1090

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An approach with `stackengine` and `scalerel`.

EDITED to provide a version that accounts for italic font slant; namely, `\tsup` for upright symbols and `\tsit` for italic symbols.  The italic font slant is specified in the definition `\fontslant`, here estimated as `.3`.

A **SUPPLEMENT** is provided at end to answer OP's wish list of doing this with arbitrary accents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\newcommand\tsup[2][2]{\ThisStyle{%
 \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifnum#1>1%
    \stackon[-5.5\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\tsup[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\SavedStyle\mathchar`~}%
  \else%
    \stackon[-4.5\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#2}{\SavedStyle\mathchar`~}%
  \fi%
}}
\def\fontslant{.3}
\newcommand\tsit[2][2]{\ThisStyle{%
 \sbox2{$\SavedStyle#2$}%
 \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifnum#1>1%
    \stackon[-5.5\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\tsit[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\hspace{\fontslant\ht2}\SavedStyle\mathchar`~}%
  \else%
    \stackon[-4.5\LMpt]{\SavedStyle#2}%
    {\hspace{\fontslant\ht2}\SavedStyle\mathchar`~}%
  \fi%
}}
\begin{document}
\[
\tsit[1]{z}\neq\tsup{\Lambda}\neq\tsup[3]{\Delta}\neq\tsit[4]{\psi}
\]
\[
\scriptstyle
\tsit[1]{z}\neq\tsup{\Lambda}\neq\tsup[3]{\Delta}\neq\tsit[4]{\psi}
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle
\tsit[1]{z}\neq\tsup{\Lambda}\neq\tsup[3]{\Delta}\neq\tsit[4]{\psi}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

Here, I create a macro `\makeitupaccents` that takes 3 arguments.  The first is the name to use it creating the accent macros, to which `it` and `up` will be added.  Thus, if `ts` is provided, macros `\tsit` and `\tsup` will be created.

Second is the accent itself and can include horizontal kerning, if needed (see MWE).

The third argument is a dimensional augmentation to the stacking gap between both the character and the accent as well as between accents.  Because I am using `scalerel`, the dimensions `\LMpt` and `\LMex` are also available here, and refer to a `pt` and and `ex`, which get shrunk in the smaller math styles (`.7pt` and `.5pt` for script and scriptscript styles, by default, likewise for `ex`).

EDITED for efficiency, using fewer `\mathchoice`s (by eliminating nested calls to `\ThisStyle`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\newcommand\fontslant{.3}
\newcommand\makeitupaccents[3]{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1up\endcsname[2][2]{\ThisStyle{%
  \csname #1upaux\endcsname[##1]{##2}}}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1upaux\endcsname[2][2]{%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifnum##1>1%
    \stackon[\dimexpr#3-5.5\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\csname 
      #1upaux\endcsname[\numexpr##1-1\relax]{##2}}{\SavedStyle#2}%
  \else%
    \stackon[\dimexpr#3-4.5\LMpt]{\SavedStyle##2}{\SavedStyle#2}%
  \fi%
}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1it\endcsname[2][2]{\ThisStyle{%
  \csname #1itaux\endcsname[##1]{##2}}}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1itaux\endcsname[2][2]{%
 \sbox2{$\SavedStyle##2$}%
 \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \ifnum##1>1%
    \stackon[\dimexpr#3-5.5\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\csname
      #1itaux\endcsname[\numexpr##1-1\relax]{##2}}%
      {\hspace{\fontslant\ht2}\SavedStyle#2}%
  \else%
    \stackon[\dimexpr#3-4.5\LMpt]{\SavedStyle##2}%
    {\hspace{\fontslant\ht2}\SavedStyle#2}%
  \fi%
}
}
\begin{document}
\makeitupaccents{ts}{\mathchar`~}{0pt}
\makeitupaccents{cs}{\mathchar`^}{0pt}
\makeitupaccents{ds}{\mathchar'26}{.7\LMpt}
\makeitupaccents{as}{\kern-\LMpt\mathchar"017E}{.2\LMpt}
\def\tmp{\tsit[1]{z}\neq\tsup{\Lambda}
  \neq\csup[3]{\Delta}\neq\csit[4]{\psi}
  \neq\dsup[3]{\Omega}\neq\dsit[2]{\omega}
  \neq\asup[3]{\mathrm{A}}\neq\asit[2]{\nu}}
\[\tmp\]
\[\scriptstyle\tmp\]
\[\scriptscriptstyle\tmp\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very cool -- thank you, +1 --, but it reintroduces the problem with horizontal alignment of the accents being off that @wipet's answer solved in the first place.

Comment: @chsk I see your point.  Maybe I'll get a chance to address that.

Comment: @chsk Please see my revision

Comment: Thanks --- that's great, now the only missing feature is arbitrary accents. (`\doubleaccent` in my question allows these; I merely used tildes as an example.)

Comment: @chsk The accent in these definitions is `\mathchar\`~`. It occurs twice in each definition.  You can make a copy of the macro(s) and play with other accents.  For example, replacing the four occurrences with `\mathchar\`^` gives a carat accent

Comment: @chsk Please see my **SUPPLEMENT**.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for all your work, much appreciated! I'll wait for a bit to see if there'll be any other answers before accepting.